# How to reset the renderer javascript context in atom-shell

Tags: electron

In a standard browser, loading a new url will reset the javascript context. ie. all global variables, compiled functions and events will be cleared, and the browser will start with a clean slate.

In atom-shell however, calling `mainWindow.loadUrl` will load the new html file, but it will keep the javascript context alive. And so variables that I would need deleted would just hang around. How can I tell atom-shell to wipe out the whole javascript context on the renderer side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `BrowserWindow.reload()` or `WebContents.reload()`.

If you are on the 'renderer' side, you can use `remote.getCurrentWindow().reload()`

https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowreload

If you want to wipe the 'javascript context' on the browser side too, you need to dereference the window and create a new window.